# ZonedDateTime.parse not working for parsing time with am or pm

Tags: java, datetime, zoneddatetime

I am learning java, trying to build a tool to convert a specific time from timezone A to timezone B based on user input (input of the time, timezone A, and timezone B). This is about the part where the tool gathers a time in a specific format to convert it into a ZonedDateTime object.

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.*;

public static String fullTime;
public static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm a");
public static ZonedDateTime newTime;

public static void getHourAndMinutes(){
        System.out.print("Please type in the time you have in mind in format hh:mm am/pm\n");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        fullTime = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(fullTime);
        newTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(fullTime, formatter);
```

I have tried to enter the time in formats like  10:30PM, 10:30 PM, 10:30pm, 10:30 pm, 10:30p, 10:30 p, all of these entries has caused exception error to be thrown, I'm getting errors like this one

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '10:30 pm' could not be parsed at index 6
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since the user entering input is just representing time you need to parse it into [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), and the other mistake is you are using the wrong pattern, `H` is hour-of-day (0-23); you need `h` in [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a");

LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("10:30 PM",formatter);
```

After parsing the input into [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) you can convert it into [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). But you must specify a date ([`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html)) as well as the time and the zone. Your code in the Question had only the time-of-day, and lacked the date and zone needed to instantiate a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = localTime.atDate(LocalDate.now()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

And then you can convert it into another zone using [withZoneSameInstant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-)

```
ZonedDateTime result = dateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York));
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I missed. Misused ZonedDateTime.parse for my time-only string.

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

A number of things, I am afraid.

1. For a `ZonedDateTime` you need a date and a time and a time zone. For parsing a string containing only time of day into a `ZonedDateTime` you would have needed to supply a default date and a default time zone. However, instead I would parse into a `LocalTime`, which is exactly a time if day without date and without time zone. After parsing you may convert. You need to decide a date for your conversion since your time zone A (and B too) probably uses a different UTC offset on different dates because of summer time (DST) and/or historic and/or future changes in their base UTC offset.
2. You need to provide a locale for your formatter to tell it in which language to assume AM and PM. For example `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH)`.
3. You need to enter AM or PM in the correct case (upper or lower case) for the locale you specified.
4. For parsing a string with hour within AM or PM from 01 through 12 you need to use lower case `hh` in the format pattern string. Not upper case `HH`, which would be for hour of day from 00 through 23.