# Convert String to DateTime object in specific format(ex. without Date)

Tags: java, datetime, time, localdate

I need to convert my `String` to time without the date. I used **SimpleDateFormat** and it worked. But what I need is from **Localdatetime** in java.

```
String str = "10:30:20 PM";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

But it is giving me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '10:30:20 PM' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 22:30:20 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Comment: What about [`LocalTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-)?

Comment: LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("10:30:20 PM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a"))

Comment: almost same to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114302/zoneddatetime-parse-not-working-for-parsing-time-with-am-or-pm/61114425#61114425`

Comment: @ernest_k your answer is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Locale` with your `DateTimeFormatter` -

```
String str = "10:30:20 PM";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a",Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(str, formatter);
System.out.println(time);
```

And also note you have to use `LocalTime.parse()` here, since your string in the date doesn't contain date part.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is LocalTime & not LocalDateTime.
You can try this as well:

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("10:45:30 PM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a"));
System.out.println(localTime);
```

If you have time in 24 hr format:

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("22:45:30", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
System.out.println(localTime);
```